# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne') with connect-session-sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, express-session

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')
nodejs                  |     at SequelizeStore.get (/InboundBackend/node_modules/connect-session-sequelize/lib/connect-session-sequelize.js:78:12)
nodejs                  |     at session (/InboundBackend/node_modules/express-session/index.js:485:11)
nodejs                  |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/InboundBackend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
nodejs                  |     at trim_prefix (/InboundBackend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
nodejs                  |     at /InboundBackend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
nodejs                  |     at Function.process_params (/InboundBackend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
nodejs                  |     at next (/InboundBackend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
nodejs                  |     at cookieParser (/InboundBackend/node_modules/cookie-parser/index.js:71:5)
nodejs                  |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/InboundBackend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
nodejs                  |     at trim_prefix (/InboundBackend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
```

I'm pretty sure I'm connecting to my database correctly:

```
const config = require("./config/config.json");

const options = config[process.env.NODE_ENV];

const sequelize = new Sequelize(options);

var SequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store);

function extendDefaultFields(defaults, session) {
  return {
    data: defaults.data,
    expires: defaults.expires,
    userId: session.userId,
  };
}

const oneHour = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 1;
var store = new SequelizeStore({
  db: sequelize,
  table: "sessions",
  extendDefaultFields: extendDefaultFields,
})


app.use(session({
  genid: 
    function(req) {
      return genuuid.v4() // use UUIDs for session IDs
    },
  secret:"test",
  store: store,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: oneHour,
    secure: true
  },
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false // when set to false the session will only be stored when it is modified, perfect for login sessions
  
}))
```

`sequelize.authenticate()` confirms that it is connect to the database

Is there some error with how I'm passing the `sequelize` object? I have no problem accessing the database otherwise.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You're not showing any code using connect-session-sequelize. The error comes from [this line](https://github.com/mweibel/connect-session-sequelize/blob/ac38630f1e9d4bdfbdc912634aeb96f962dbf112/lib/connect-session-sequelize.js#L78) but you don't even seem to be using the package (at least in the code you have here)

Comment: `SequelizeStore()` is imported from `connect-session-sequelize`, that is what I'm using. I've updated the code with the import

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I forgot to add the final line `store.sync()`.